# Where to place third party push code in Android?

Tags: android, service, coding-style, pusher

I must use 'Pusher' library for Android. I would like to receive push notifications during whole phone usage, not only during application usage. Since it's a third party library I wonder where to put it's callbacks.

Should it be long running `Service`, or there is a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Service with [startForeground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29) . App users may hate you.